# Visual Studio Xamarin Emulator not available

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am new to the Visual Studio Xamarin. I am trying to build a sample Android App using the Visual Studio Xamarin.

I create a Android Blank Project.When I run the program without adding any code  it is throwing an error "Please select a valid device before running the application."

There is no default device available in the Device list.

I tired below steps to resolve this error

1. I tried to update the Android SDK and add a device
2. I uninstalled and installed the Android-SDK and Xamarin again.

Both of them did not worked.

Adding a Error image.  [image]

Please help if anyone come across this error or know how to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Learn [ask] and [mcve]. It's only a 5 minute read and will save you hours. We want to help, but we need some context. Please [edit] your question to reflect it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something descriptive of the problem or question. Your current title simply repeats the information you've already provided in the tags. The title should be informative enough to be relevant when seen by a future user here in a search result, and what you've written so far has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

To run an emulator in normal account that was created as administrator.
2 Steps:

- Move 1 folder and 1 .ini file
- Change paths values in 2 config files

**First,** move your emulator's .ini file and folder from admin's account.

- Source - **C:\Users\{admin account}.android\avd**
- Destination - **C:\Users\{YOUR account}.android\avd**

**Second,** change the emulator paths in 2 config files

- Config file 1 - **{emulator name}.ini**

  (1 key-value)

  path
- Config file 2 - **{emulator folder}\hardware-qemu.ini**

  (4 key-value)

  hw.sdCard.path

  disk.cachePartition.path

  disk.dataPartition.path

  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path

Answer (score 0):

Try these links :

Are you trying to debug in real device or emulator ?

If you are using real device you just want to [Set Up Device for Development](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/)

In case of Emulators :

1. [Android SDK Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/)
2. [Visual Studio Android Emulator](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/visual-studio-android-emulator/)

**Edit 1**

Just try to run **Android Virtual Device (AVD) Manager** as administrator.

When it's opens the window try to start one of your created emulator from the displaying list, if you haven't created one yet, click create button to create and then start it.

Wait for a while (may take time too long time to start), when the emulator is ready, check for it in your visual studio.

---

Your error states that the device is offline(occurred when device is not connected, emulator not started properly).

---

Other than using an Android SDK Emulator,it will be better to use **Visual Studio Android Emulator**, **Xamarin Android Player**, or **Genymotion** as emulators, which will give you good performance.

Comment: I am trying to run the program in the emulator. I do have installed the Android SDK Emulator. I added the device as well using the as per the instruction still the device is not there and I am getting same error.

Comment: *Try these links* is never an acceptable answer here. Answers contain the content here, in the answer itself, with external links used only as an additional reference. If your entire answer is based on external content, and the link is not available (off-line, moved, deleted, etc.), your answer has zero value to future readers. If it's unclear what the original question is asking, leave a comment on the question itself asking for clarification.

Comment: Thanks Vaikesh. Worked now. As you said it takes long time to add the device. However not sure why my question is down voted.